# Connect Facebook like button on website - do I need an app for that?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-app-settings

I created a Facebook page for my website, and I have added the like button to various product pages. Whenever I load the page, I get the error that I need a valid app ID. So I created the app and added the website as a platform, but I keep getting this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I'd like to know:

- If I just want a like button on my page, do I really need to create an app?
- If so, what does the above error mean?

[image]

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter an app id while using the like button- so yes, you need to create an app- not a big deal, right?

Now this error is due to the fact that, you have not added the correct url in the "Site URL" when you chose website as platform.

eg: If your page is something like: http://my-ste.com/my-page/, then you should write the **Site URL** as http://my-site.com/ - this will remove this error.

Hope that help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Creating the App ID is not a big deal indeed, it's just that the name "App" seemed like much more than just a like button on the website. I verified the URL in the platform and it is correct. Still getting the message though:-(

Comment: This isnt possible. Can you give the website url?

Comment: Added a screenshot to show the settings for the platform

Comment: 1. Make sure app id is correct. 2. Add app domain: `wijnvandekaap.nl`

Comment: Still no luck. App ID and website domains have been added, but I am still getting the same message.